# map string to function

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to do this but it does not work
this is my error:

> must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in
>   ‘((test*)this)->test::mapping.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator[], void (test::*)(int), std::less >, std::allocator, void (test::*)(int)> > >((*(const
>   key_type*)(& str))) (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->*
>   ((test*)this)->test::mapping.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator[], void (test::*)(int), std::less >, std::allocator, void (test::*)(int)> > >((*(const
>   key_type*)(& str)))) (...)’

```
test.h:

#include....
using namespace std;
class test
{
    public:
       std::map<std::string, void(test::*)(int)> mapping;
    void Add(int);
};

test.cpp:

test::test()
{
   mapping["Add"]=&test::Add;
   string str = "Add";
   this.*mapping[str](3);// dosnt work!!!!
}

void test::Add(int a)
{
   cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Dosnt work, please help me.

Comment: There are multiple errors in this code..

Comment: What on earth are you doing with this code? Porting C++ to PERL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `this` is a pointer, you need to use `->*` instead of `.*`. Additionally, some parentheses are needed.

```
(this->*mapping[str])(3);
```

Comment: @didierc it's necessary because the Standard says so, as stated in `[expr.call]p1` in the Standard.

Comment: Oh, right, it's a pointer to member to *this* very instance. I didn't see that (knee jerk reaction beware!).